# Does upgrading to OSX Lion have ANY caveats for development using Xcode?

Tags: iphone, xcode, macos, osx-lion

Simple question, I want to know if anyone has had any weird or annoying problems with developing iphone apps in Xcode after upgrading to Lion. I remember having issues when Snow Leopard first launched. Are there any early adopter penalties here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to download the latest Xcode 4.1 to do development on Lion. 4.0.x won't work.

You also have to learn how to scroll down pages like a flight simulator (you can turn it off). If you got used to the neat gestures in Snow Leopard, then get ready to completely start over again with new ones (no going back on Lion). Three finger web page navigation doesn't work, 4 finger application switching doesn't work, and a new "explosion" gesture is used for desktop and mission control.

Comment: You can turn off "natural" scrolling if you want (Settings > Mouse)

Answer (score 6):

A big one for me: no more PowerPC emulation via Rosetta in 10.7 - important to think about if you need to do testing for legacy PowerPC code.

Fortunately you can still use Xcode 3.2.6 though if you don't want or need to use Xcode 4.1 - if Xcode 3.2.6 is installed prior to upgrading t Lion then it should still work, alternatively there are [instructions](http://anatomicwax.tumblr.com/post/7906770311/installing-xcode-3-2-6-on-lion) available for installed Xcode 3.2.6 when Lion is already installed.

Comment: Installing Xcode 3.2.6 On Lion: http://anatomicwax.tumblr.com/post/7906770311/installing-xcode-3-2-6-on-lion

Answer (score 5):

I just had the problem, that I had to upgrade to Xcode 4.1 because lower versions of Xcode don't work on Lion. ;-)

Comment: @Sandro Meier, Not related to the question, but I can't find this in google. can I use XCode 4.2 in Snow Leopard for ios 5 development, or is Lion required? I will really be grateful, if you answer. Thanks a lot!

Comment: On the developer page apple has also a build of 4.2 for Snow Leopard. So I think you will also be able to develope on Snow Leopard for iOS 5. ;-) (But I didn't try it myself)

Answer (score 4):

The only thing i have noticed so far is that if you run Xcode in fullscreen mode, simulator can't be on same screen... And yes, you have to download new Xcode 4.1 from appstore... Everything else is pretty much amazing :-D

Answer (score 2):

When you try to install Xcode 3.2.6 on Lion, Xcode toolset is greyed out and marked as skip. There is a simpler way to install it then those once described above. Here is the steps:

1. Mount the developer tools dmg
2. Open Terminal and run these two commands:

   export COMMAND_LINE_INSTALL=1

   open "/Volumes/Xcode and iOS SDK/Xcode and iOS SDK.mpkg"

Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

Be prepared for the new Xcode to remove the /Developer directory as a part of its cleanup process. This will wipe out QT in the process since it's installed there as well.

So if you want to keep QT intact you should skip Xcode's cleanup step or install a fresh QT afterwards.